# Read file content from network path in Windows CE

Tags: compact-framework, windows-ce, opennetcf

Is there possible in Windows CE 6.0 devices (Compact Framework) read file content over WiFi from files stored  in network using UNC path?

Or in this case should I use FTP server or develop my own server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the network share connection by P/Invoking [WNetAddConnection3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa917445.aspx).  Once that's done, you can copy just like you would any other local file.